# Java remove item from arraylist

Tags: java

Pardon the French names for variables, it do be like that. But I was wondering if I could use a third removeif function to remove grande and petites from original and then show original with the removed values. I know I could use a for loop and I might be getting ahead of myself as beginner but I am trying out new stuff.

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpWdA.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never post code as an image. Second, yes of course you can have such a `removeIf`. Basically, you want to remove the value if the value is in `grande` or in `petites`. Like,

```
original.removeIf(v -> grande.contains(v) || petites.contains(v));
```